# I want to use Integrated Graphics for OS rendering and NVIDIA Graphics for Minecraft

Tags: nvidia, graphics, gpu

I want to use Nvidia GPU for games and Intel GPU for the OS rendering because my GPU starts to overheat while I play games like Minecraft

I am on Ubuntu  20.04
I have a Intel Corporation UHD Graphics and a NVIDIA Corporation Quadro T2000

Comment: If you're talking about a desktop you can depending on the motherboard's firmware options. In a laptot with hybrid graphics you can't.

Comment: It's a Laptop with 2 GPUs, I read somewhere the by using NVIDIA-on demand mode, you can do this

Comment: No, you can't. "On demand" means it *switches* automatically or it should but it doesn't work correctly in most systems.